# Is the xul button element in a firefox sidebar editable with CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, xul

I have been trying to change the style of buttons in my firefox extension sidebar with a CSS file (change skin). However, the buttons don't seem to take over the style changes. I tried both background images and just changing color etc., which are both not working. 
Is it possible to influence the button style at all in my firefox extension sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

Your button's css needs to have -moz-appearance: none; to do any styling on it otherwise you'll get the OS native look and feel.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Skinning_XUL_Files_by_Hand) helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
 -moz-appearance:none;
```

must be in the css button class or id